# Unable to create a case when case owner is assigned to a queue in email to case

Tags: email, email2case

Im trying to create a case through email to case.

Im sending the email to the routing address as part of unit testing and found a strange issue here.

1. Im able to create a case when im trying to do it by assigning the case owner to any user, Im able to create a case expected.
2. Now there is one more option to assign case owner to queue. Im not able to create a record.

Could some one guide me if we have any pre checks to be done before assigning to a queue.

Comment: In option 2 - the Case isn't created at all? or it is created but not assigned to a Queue?  If you debug using the Email-to-Case context user you can gain insight

Comment: The case is not at all created

Comment: Check the debug log